# Changing the header of the bliss wordpress template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this wordpress template: http://bluth.is/wordpress/bliss/

and I want to change the header. The subtitle should be UNDER the logo and not next to it. I have tried to make the content bigger and the logo smaller but nothing works. Any ideas?

The Code from the header.php:

```
    <div class="span9" style="height:90px;">
    <p>
    <a class="brand brand-image" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><?php if(!of_get_option('disable_description')){ ?></a>
    </p>
    <small><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></small></div><?php } ?>
```

Comment: maybe make p and small inline-blocks see what happens and make sure they have enough width to expand

Comment: thanks, i have already tried that :(

Answer (score 0):

Using **CSS** margin you can move it wherever you want.

I don't know exactly the using pixles but here is how it suppose to be:

```
margin: 30px -100px 0;
```

Ofcourse there is a better way using photoshop to edit the logo and add him this subtitle.

Comment: but when I use photoshop its not SEO optimized

Comment: Then use margin, either way search engines doesn't actually care about 3 words or bigger image ,I'm sure it's not critical.

Comment: left margin wors perfekt, but nothing changes on the height, it is still on the top

Comment: try use padding-top: 50px;

Comment: I would suggest you try use top, bottom, all those phisyicall position changes elements.